# Jpa TypedQuery and byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, image, jpa, serialization

I have a typedquery like this:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c.id , c.name, g.id, g.brand, g.price,g.goodsImage FROM Category c JOIN c.goods g WHERE g.user.userId=:userId and g.class=:type",Object[].class);
            query.setParameter("userId", userId);
            query.setParameter("type", type.toUpperCase());
```

Where g.goodsImage is a array of bytes.
What I don't know,  is how do I o convert the object[5] to a byte[]?

I tried to serialize the object, but I don't have any luck.

This is what I tried:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 ObjectOutput out;
                try {
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
                     out.writeObject(object[5]);
                     byte[] image = new byte[ bos.size()];
                     image  = bos.toByteArray();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

If I do:

```
  TypedQuery<byte[]> query = em.createQuery("SELECT g.goodsImage From Goods g ",byte[].class);
```

This works, but the first Typed Query wont.

Do you know how to convert object[] to byte[]?

Comment: Your query returns results with each row as an `Object[]`, so what Class is the 6th element of the result row ?

Comment: Yes, my query returns N numbers of rows for example. The 6th element (g.goodImage is a byte[] type), I store an image file.

Comment: and what is it returned as ? If that element in the QUERY RETURN is a byte[] then you case that element to byte[]. Why not update your question with the execution of the query, so we have the result object shown?

Comment: Oh my god, you are ok. Only casting will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Doing this works goods.goodsImage = (byte[]) object[5]; I think that i need to serialize and all that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As DN1 told me, casting the object will work:

```
goods.goodsImage = (byte[]) object[5];
```